# Extract numbers then sum using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, list, sum, integer

I'm trying to extract all the numbers from a text file using re.findall() and compute the sum using a for-loop. What I was getting at first was a list of lists, so I put them in one overall list and tried to convert each number into integers. But the answer I get is different from provided answer. Can someone take a look at my code and see if I overlooked anything? Link to the text file is: http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_376410.txt

```
handle = open('regex_sum.txt','r')
import re

lst = list()
for line in handle:
    b = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if b:
        lst.append(b)

total = 0

for numbers in lst:
    for num in numbers:
       c = int(num)
       total = total + c
print total
```

P.S I did figure out why I got a different answer. My code extracted a few irrelevant numbers at the beginning of the output '0, 8, 4, 376410' which was not present in the text file. Anybody know how to fix my code so these numbers don't appear again?

Comment: *How* is it different?  Did you check the generated list against what you expected?

Comment: What's the expected output? What did you get?

Comment: I got '814051', the answer is supposed to end with '629'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend

Comment: For what is worth, my result is 437629.

Comment: P.S I did figure out why I got a different answer. My code extracted a few irrelevant numbers at the beginning of the output '0, 8, 4, 376410' which was not present in the text file. Do you know how to fix my code so these numbers don't appear again?

Comment: how is the answer supposed to be 629 when the first number in the file is 5162?

Comment: end with 629...

Comment: 376410 is in your filename, (on the web url anyway)... is there anything more in your code? Open your local txt file, maybe it included some header from the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the expected answer should end with 629 then you should change `append` to `extend` (see the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/3462319)). While you're extending you might as well convert the findings into ints. Then you can use the default `sum` function.

```
import re

handle = open('regex_sum.txt','r')

lst = []
for line in handle:
    b = re.findall('\d+', line)
    if b:
        lst.extend([int(x) for x in b])
        # this also works if you want to use append
        #for x in b:
        #    lst.append(int(x))

print(sum(lst))
# outputs: 437629
```